# UIPanGestureRecognizer elastic effect issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I've added a UIPanGestureRecognizer to a cell, allowing the user to slide it horizontally. When the cell x origin becomes more than 50, I want the cell to move more slowly, like happens with UIScrollView limits, for example, but I'm having a problem: the cell doesn't follow my finger as it should.

I slide my finger from left to right on the screen multiple times, and when I finish the cell's in a different position from the starting position.

This is the code I'm using to move the cell (my guess is there's something wrong with the way I'm creating the elastic effect when it reaches 50):

```
- (void)slideCell:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGFloat horizontalTranslation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x;

    if (panGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGFloat retention = 1;

        if (self.frame.origin.x > 50) retention = 5;

        [self setCenter:CGPointMake(self.center.x+horizontalTranslation/retention, self.center.y)];
    }

    [panGestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're resetting the translation to zero all the time so you lose the knowledge about the absolute distance that the users touch has moved. If you change your algorithm so that the frame is set based on the translation without resetting (the absolute translation) then your calculation will be accurate when you drag back.

---

Experiment with different algorithms, try something like:

```
CGFloat tx = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x;

[self setCenter:CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + (tx - (tx > 50 ? sqrt(tx - 50) : 0)), originalCenter.y)];
```

If the deceleration is too fast, try using `powf` so you can specify the factor.

Comment: I tried doing it like that too, and it worked, but I couldn't find out a way to make the elastic effect. Do you know how could I make it?

Comment: Why didn't you show that algorithm and ask that question? If the calculated position is > 50, subtract a value based on some rule (square root, log, ...) depending on the effect you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have a functional algorithm. The best approach I've thought is `[self setCenter:CGPointMake(originalCenter.x+horizontalTranslation-0.8*(horizontalTranslation-50), originalCenter.y)];` but it doesn't feel smooth...

Comment: Added an idea to get you started

Comment: It didn't work... I'll look for a better algorithm. Meanwhile, I'll use `[self setCenter:CGPointMake(originalCenter.x+horizontalTranslation-0.8*(horizontalTran‌​slation-50), originalCenter.y)];`, which doesn't work perfectly, but is a good approach.

Comment: Have you found any other good algorithms? I'm stuck in the same problem.